# Laying out a dynamic search screen in iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, layout

I need to design a search screen in iOs with several option categories (Such as Color, red, blue, yellow etc. Size, medium, small, big...)
The categories come from the database and are dynamic.
I first thought about using a table but I also on top of that some free text search and maybe other options...So maybe it's not the best way to go...

What would you use for that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite general, what do you mean by categories? Filtering options?

For search options in iOS you can use [UISearchController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller)

If you want to adjust filtering options, you can use sliders, segmented controls, switches, buttons, pickerviews etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sorry it's might not be clear enough.

Let's put it like that, I want to make a search screen that all together will have like 30+ options.

Most of them are just toggle boxes within categories.
This comes from database.
Then you have some "permanent" fields, such as a freetext field, sliders etc.

Like total screen would be :

Color:
   Red (include Yes/no)
   Blue (include Yes/no)
   Yellow (include Yes/no)
Size
   Small (include Yes/no)
   Medium (include yes/no)
   Big (include Yes/no)
Quality
   Low (include Yes/no)
   Average (include Yes/no)
   High (include Yes/no)
   Highest (include Yes/no)

Name (optional free text)
Cost (optional min / max)

Search button / Reset button

As such, what is the best way to construct the screen, manually adding the controls, or using a listView/tableview inside a scrollview with a the bottom the input box etc ?

Comment: so... no ideas so far, or it still too general ?